# Unable to connect to Azure Database from an Azure pipeline

Tags: mysql, bash, azure, azure-pipelines

I've setup and Azure Database for MySQL. I am able to connect fine through the Azure Cloud Shell using

`mysql -h ...mysql.database.azure.com --ssl -u web -p`

Now what I want to do is to be able to connect to this database from an Azure pipeline. The purpose is to use the database to track the version numbers for our artifacts.

My initial test pipeline yaml looks like

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- bash: |
    mysql -h ...mysql.database.azure.com -u web -p -D applications -N -e "select version, snapshot from releases where name='$1'" | while IFS= read -r value
    do
    echo $value
    done
```

However, the bash script never completes. The indicator simply spins and I have yet to receive a timeout or any type of error.

Since the database is setup to use SSL, my next iteration of the pipeline looked like

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- bash: |
    mysql -h ...mysql.database.azure.com --ssl -u web -p -D applications -N -e "select version, snapshot from releases where name='$1'" | while IFS= read -r value
    do
    echo $value
    done
```

which mirrors the same connection I use in Cloud Shell. However this time I receive the following output

```
Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.182.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/b5b259c5-bee8-4e95-b1c6-50a98baaf7dc.sh
mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--ssl'.
Finishing: Bash
```

Finally I tried downloading the recommended certificate and adding it to the connection

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
      secureFile: DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem
- bash: |
    mysql -h ...mysql.database.azure.com --ssl_cert $(Agent.TempDirectory)/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem -u web -p -D applications -N -e "select version, snapshot from releases where name='$1'" | while IFS= read -r value
    do
    echo $value
    done
```

which again resulted in the task simply sitting there with no output. I'm not sure if this is a firewall issue(meaning I need to add a rule to the database firewall settings)? If this is the case, then how would I determine what range of IP addresses to allow?

By the way, I already have the following rule set

```
  {
    "endIpAddress": "55.226.19.255",
    "id": "/subscriptions/1fa96361-56c7-4090-8823-26ae03e4c38d/resourceGroups/VS-americas-manufacturing-Group/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/mfg-mysql-eus-1/firewallRules/cloudshell",
    "name": "cloudshell",
    "resourceGroup": "VS-americas-manufacturing-Group",
    "startIpAddress": "52.226.19.0",
    "type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules"
  }
```

but this doesn't seem to work for the pipelines.

So what setting changes do I need to make, either on the server or in my pipeline, to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your scripts and make changes to your database in Azure Database for MySQL. You could use [Azure Database for MySQL Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-mysql-deployment?view=azure-devops):

```
# Azure Database for MySQL deployment
# Run your scripts and make changes to your Azure Database for MySQL
- task: AzureMysqlDeployment@1
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: # Or alias azureSubscription
    ServerName:
    #DatabaseName: # Optional
    SqlUsername:
    SqlPassword:
    #TaskNameSelector: 'SqlTaskFile' # Optional. Options: SqlTaskFile, InlineSqlTask
    #SqlFile: # Required when taskNameSelector == SqlTaskFile
    #SqlInline: # Required when taskNameSelector == InlineSqlTask
    #SqlAdditionalArguments: # Optional
    #IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect' # Options: AutoDetect, IPAddressRange
    #StartIpAddress: # Required when ipDetectionMethod == IPAddressRange
    #EndIpAddress: # Required when ipDetectionMethod == IPAddressRange
    #DeleteFirewallRule: true # Optional
```

Comment: I will look more into this. All I really need to do is to run two queries, one to get some values and one to insert new values. This will allow me to do the same? Thank you

Comment: This task could run your scripts and make changes to your Azure Database for MySQL.

Comment: How's your issue going? Is it helpful?

Comment: My apologies. I've been diverted to another project. As I get a few spare minutes, I **WILL** try this solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This worked but then generated `Could not retrieve an access token for the managed service principal`. I will look this up and see if I have the authorization to create it

Comment: I have tried this but somehow while execution the task fails with an error
"Error: The MySQL server list is empty. The MySQL server host name is invalid."
I am not able to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same issue as me and finds this post...

One of the proposed solutions is to use a yaml-task AzureMysqlDeployment@1 to deploy an ef migrations script. But it gives the error:

"Error: The MySQL server list is empty. The MySQL server host name is invalid."

According to the [microsoft documentation for the pipeline task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-mysql-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) it seems that the task (currently) only works for mysql single server database on Azure.  Azure recommends creating a flexible server mysql database for all new development, which I did an hence it did not to work in my case.

Instead I got it to work by using a commandline task and running a mysql command

```
- task: CmdLine@2       
  displayName: Run SQL Scripts in MySQL database
  inputs:
  script: 'mysql --host=$(mysql-server) --user=$(mysql-user) //
      --password=$(mysql-password) -D $(mysql-database-name) //
      --execute="source path/to/script.sql"'
```